# Could someone explain this for me - for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)

Tags: syntax, for-loop

Could someone explain in the simplest terms, as if you are talking to an idiot (because you are), what this code is actually saying/doing

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
```

Comment: There is chat on SO: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: There is a chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's a loop that says, okay, for every time that `i` is smaller than 8, I'm going to do whatever is in the code block. Whenever `i` reaches 8, I'll stop. After each iteration of the loop, it increments `i` by 1 (`i++`), so that the loop will eventually stop when it meets the `i < 8` (`i` becomes 8, so no longer is smaller than) condition.

For example, this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Will output: `01234567`

See how the code was executed 8 times?

In terms of arrays, this can be helpful when you don't know the size of the array, but you want to operate on every item of it. You can do:

**Disclaimer: This following code will vary dependent upon language, but the principle remains the same**

```
Array yourArray;

for (int i = 0; i < yourArray.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(yourArray[i]);
}
```

The difference here is the number of execution times is **entirely dependent** on the size of the array, so it's dynamic.

Comment: This helps a lot thank you. Obviously it raises questions as well but those will be answered when I look at other parts of my code. Thank you for the fast response :)!

Comment: @Gandeh No problems, if there's anything you want me to clarify just let me know.

Answer (score 9):

> for <strike>(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)</strike>

It's a `for` loop, which will execute the next statement a number of times, depending on the conditions inside the parenthesis.

> <strike>for (</strike>int i = 0<strike>; i < 8; i++)</strike>

Start by setting `i = 0`

> <strike>for (int i = 0;</strike> i < 8<strike>; i++)</strike>

Continue looping while `i < 8`.

> <strike>for (int i = 0; i < 8;</strike> i++<strike>)</strike>

Every time you've been around the loop, increase `i` by 1.

For example;

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    do(i);
```

will call do(0), do(1), ... do(7) in order, and stop when `i` reaches 8 (ie `i < 8` is false)

Comment: Heh - clever application of strikethrough :)

Answer (score 4):

The generic view of a loop is

`for (initialization; condition; increment-decrement){}`

The first part initializes the code.  The second part is the condition that will continue to run the loop as long as it is true.  The last part is what will be run after each iteration of the loop. The last part is typically used to increment or decrement a counter, but it doesn't have to.

Comment: Okay so you're saying

i = 0

if i reaches 8 reset to 0

on each loop add one to i

{
do this
}



i

Comment: No, your code says that i will initially be 0 at the start.  'Initially' is the key word, that part is not used ever again.  The condition is then checked.  In your case 0 < 8 so the loop will continue.  After each run through of the code contained in the loop, the third part will be called.  So 'i' is incremented by one.  The condition is checked (1 < 8) so the loop keeps going until i = 8 in which case the condition will fail and the loop will exit.

Answer (score 4):

```
for(<first part>; <second part>; <third part>)
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

This code is evaluated like this:

1. Run <first part>
2. If <second part> is false, skip to the end
3. DoStuff();
4. Run <third part>
5. Goto 2

So for your example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

1. Set i to 0.
2. If i is not less than 8, skip to the end.
3. DoStuff();
4. i++
5. Goto 2

So the loop runs one time with i set to each value from 0 to 7.  Note that i is incremented to 8, but then the loop ends immediately afterwards; it does not run with i set to 8.

Answer (score 4):

it's the same as think the next:

"starting with i = 0, while i is less than 8, and adding one to i at the end of the parenthesis, do the instructions between brackets"

It's also the same as:

```
while( i < 8 )
{
    // instrucctions like:
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    i++;
}
```

the For sentences is a basis of coding, and it's as useful as necessary its understanding.

It's the way to repeat n-times the same instrucction, or browse ( or do something with each element) an array

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  //code
}
```

In simplest terms

```
int i = 0;
if (i < 8) //code
i = i + 1; //i = 1
if (i < 8) //code
i = i + 1;  //i = 2
if (i < 8) //code
i = i + 1;  //i = 3
if (i < 8) //code
i = i + 1; //i = 4
if (i < 8) //code
i = i + 1; //i = 5
if (i < 8) //code
i = i + 1; //i = 6
if (i < 8) //code
i = i + 1; //i = 7
if (i < 8) //code
i = i + 1; //i = 8
if (i < 8) //code - this if won't pass
```